# The simplest way to show a toast notification in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, toast

I've been looking for a way to show an offline (not pushed from a server) toast notification on WP7 for a while now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to show the notification while your application is running, you can use the `ToastPrompt` from the coding4fun toolkit: http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/

If you want to show the notification while your app isn't running, you can use the `ShellToast` class from a background agent: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltoast(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Within a background task, simply call this method:

```
    public static void makeToast(string toastText)
    {
        //Make a new toast with content "text"
        ShellToast toast = new ShellToast();
        toast.Title = "Toast Title: ";
        toast.Content = toastText;
        //toast.NavigationUri = new Uri();
        toast.Show();
    }
```